# How to get Flutter's webview to work with local assets loaded from local html?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin

I have an html file which loads css file, font and image files. Currently my webview loads without loading any of these secondary files, images aren't shown, css isn't shown. I'm trying like that:

```
    loadHtmlFromAssets();
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Web", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      url: 'about:blank',
      withZoom: false,
      withJavascript: true,
      allowFileURLs: true,
      withLocalUrl: true,
      localUrlScope: 'assets/maphtml/',
      withLocalStorage: true,
    );

loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/maphtml/zemelapis.html');
    flutterWebViewPlugin.reloadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")).toString());
  }
```

Assets in html have an assumed prefix of zemelapis.html location, e.g.

```
<script src="js/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add js content to html body before generating the Uri

```
static void loadHtmlFromAssets(String fileText) async{

String htmlText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/maphtml/zemelapis.html');
final String jsText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/maphtml/js/image-map-pro.min.js'); //set exact js file path

//add js to html body
htmlText = '${htmlText}<script>${jsText}</script>';

flutterWebViewPlugin.reloadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(htmlText, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")).toString());
```

}